# Missing Java EE implementation

Tags: unit-testing, maven, glassfish, java-ee-6

I'm still unable to make my unit tests work. When I'm executing the test, I get `ClassFormatException`: *Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file `javax/ejb/EJBAccessException`*. This I've written in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But it does not work. If I open the file `repo/org/glassfish/javaee/6.0/javaee-6.0.jar` in text editor, it contains some HTML text only. Have you any idea what's wrong? Where can I find the proper `javaee-6.0.jar`? If I open the one in `glassfish3/glassfish/lib`, it contains only some `pom.xml`, nothing more.

I have data layer consisting of entities accessed via session beans. This layer is packaged and deployed as JAR. The error is matter of presentation layer. There is no EJB. But I'm using Spring MVC. It loads controllers at the beginning. And several controllers are EJB clients. That shouldn't do matter, but one of them contains line `import javax.ejb.EJBAccessException`. When the (let say) Spring loader is loading this class, loading process fails with above mentioned exception. Thus I need the Java EE implementation to proceed the test.

But this question is actually more general. That's not first time, what I have encountered this error: dependency JAR was not valid and when I was looking inside, I saw regular HTML code.

Btw: I'm astonished, that I still haven't found the proper answer to this fundamental question overall the Internet.

Comment: Could you give us more info. What are you unit testing ? EJB ? what are you using ? JUnit, Arquillian ?

Answer (score 1):

The local repository is corrupted, `jar` files should not contain `HTML` content. Maybe one of your projects downloaded broken artifacts from a corrupted remote repository. It's possible that your current project is fine but another use a corrupt mirror etc.

I'd delete the whole `repo/org/glassfish/javaee/6.0/` directory. Maven will download the artifacts again if they're required. Run an `mvn clean install` after the delete and check the url of the `org/glassfish/javaee/6.0/javaee-6.0.jar`. It shows which is the corrupted repository if the downloaded artifacts (i.e. jars) are contains HTML again.

Anyway, I don't think that you need this dependency since the `javax.ejb.EJBAccessException` is in the API (`javaee-api.jar`). (And it's not in the [central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.glassfish%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javaee%22).)
 I'd remove the glassfish dependency and try running the test first. If it still fails I'd run the test with `java -verbose:class` and check which `jar` contains the loaded `EJBAccessException.class`.

Comment: _I think the other `javax.javaee-api` is enough._ I don't thing so. (See my updated post - it is the very reason). In my settings I have this: `http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish`. There is just some `javaee-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in this repo, but does not contain any class-file. It contains some Maven metadata only.